# I'm trying to read contents of text file in python from a different directory - get file not found error

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Aug 19 22:06:43 2019

@author: Om
"""

import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

# Define the symbol list
symbol = []
# Select file to access
filename=input('Enter the name of file to access')
filename=filename+'.txt'
print(filename)

with open('D:\\om\\python_stock_script\\filename')as f:
    for line in f:
        symbol.append(line.strip())
f.close
```

I get the following error:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.6.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('D:/Om/python_stock_script/StockEval.py', wdir='D:/Om/python_stock_script')

Enter the name of file to accessDivStock
DivStock.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-95059502a977>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Om/python_stock_script/StockEval.py', wdir='D:/Om/python_stock_script')

  File "C:\Users\Om\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Om\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Om/python_stock_script/StockEval.py", line 22, in <module>
    with open('D:\\om\\python_stock_script\\filename')as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\om\\python_stock_script\\filename'
```

If I replace the name of the file, which is "DivStock.txt" the code works. The file exists in the specified directory because I put it there. I tried several approaches including "pathlib". Obviously I am doing something wrong. I want to be abler to choose tjhe file to select. Please help

Comment: Probably a typo: Your working directory is in `D:/Om/...`, but you are trying to open a file in `D:/om/...`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are opening a file with the static name of "filename". Unless such a file exists in that directory (a file named: "filename") you will get an error.

```
with open('D:\\om\\python_stock_script\\filename')as f:
```

I am assuming what you want to do is insert the filename that you inputted earlier at the end of that the file directory. Right now you are not doing that, all you are doing is placing a static path to a file called "filename". If you really want "filename" to be replaced with your variable you have to use some string interpolation. Here is a simple way to do that:

```
with open(f"D:\\om\\python_stock_script\\{filename}")as f:
```

By placing the f in front of the quotes you let python know you will be having variables mixed in within that string. To distinguish a variable from the rest of the string encapsulate it in curly braces. This should already work fine but if you want to clean it up a bit you could get rid of the double backslashes by placing an "r" in front of the string and using single backslashes.

```
with open(rf"D:\om\python_stock_script\{filename}")as f:
```

Also you do not need to have the line:

```
f.close
```

Don't get me wrong this is important if you preside it with `f.open()` and in that case not closing the file could cause problems. However, since you are using `with open() as f:` that is not necessary as python automatically closes the file once it exits the with block.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The string you pass to the method open is broken. You are including the variable name filename into the string. One way to do it is :

```
with open('D:\\om\\python_stock_script\\'+filename)as f:
```

If you want to know more, read about string concatenation.